# Public Facing Recursive DNS Servers - iptables rules

Tags: domain-name-system, ddos

We run public-facing recursive DNS servers on Linux machines. We've been used for DNS amplification attacks. Are there any recommended `iptables` rules that would help mitigate these attacks?

The obvious solution is just to limit outbound DNS packets to a certain traffic level. But I was hoping to find something a little bit more clever so that an attack just blocks off traffic to the victim IP address.

I've searched for advice and suggestions, but they all seem to be "don't run public-facing recursive name servers". Unfortunately, we are backed into a situation where things that are not easy to change will break if we don't do so, and this is due to decisions made more than a decade ago before these attacks were an issue.

Comment: The people advising you not to run a public facing recursive name server are right.  Can you explain _why_ it's apparently necessary?

Comment: @Alnitak: Things that are not easy to change will break if we don't do so due to decisions made more than a decade ago.

Comment: yes, I saw that in the original question.  Can you explain _why_ that configuration is necessary?

Comment: @Alnitak: Because things that are not easy to change rely on it. These are devices that have their firmware burned in and are deployed around the world, many in secure facilities that we don't even have access to.

Comment: Do your embedded systems support TCP name resolution instead of UDP?  If so, how easy would it be to disable UDP for resolution?

Comment: @MikePennington: I wish, but no, it doesn't. It's broken in a lot of ways. New systems don't use this scheme at all, but we still have to support these legacy systems. Even if it did, we can't touch the configuration on these machines. Now that they've processed live data, we cannot touch them. (We can only replace them, but that would incur expenses to approve the new hardware and software that our customers don't wish to bear and we are required to support them for a few more years yet.)

Comment: what kind of records and to which domains do these devices require to function?  i.e. do they just lookup updates.yourcompany.com or is requesting a vast number of domains integral to the operation of the device (i.e. you're a mail/web/anti-spam appliance)?

Comment: @gravyface: It could potentially be looking up anything. In practice, it may be limited. I could try to to identify something in the devices' DNS query that I can use to fingerprint it. It's worth a shot.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz how many devices in the field are we talking about here? 10s, 100s, 1000s?  Do you have a direct contact/relationship with the clients, or are these wholesale/OEM/distributor customers?

Comment: @gravyface: 100's. We have a direct relationship with the clients. But they cannot allow us to touch any devices that have handled their live data, nor can they install new hardware/software without going through an expensive (to them) approval process. We basically have to wait for the support period on these devices to end.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz how many organizations are we dealing with? 100s? (i.e. 1 device per organization) or "dozens"?

Comment: @gravyface: It's an odd split. Most organizations have one. Some have two, three or four. And there are three organizations that have very large numbers. Many of them are government and military or quasi-military. (However, most of these probably are in 'non-Internet' mode and so don't even try to use the public nameservers.)

Comment: @DavidSchwartz what DNS server are you using?

Comment: @davidschwartz the obvious solution would seem to be to only accept DNS requests from clients with these devices.  Why won't a default deny and a client whitelist work?

Comment: DNS server is bind. A client whitelist won't work because we have no idea what IP addresses the clients are using.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz have a tcpdump running yet?

Comment: Trying stopping people from running public facing recursive name server is not a solution : 1. There are too many 2. Some want/need them. Still very experimental but a patch for bind9 is available : http://www.redbarn.org/dns/ratelimits hope it will help mitigating. Close/restrict open recursive server for now but be aware it wont prevent attacks : http://blog.cloudflare.com/deep-inside-a-dns-amplification-ddos-attack

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The whole thing kind of reeks of a "not my problem" scenario that's not really your fault and should/could be 100% resolved by taking the appropriate action, regardless of how "difficult" or "hard" it is, and that's **terminating your open recursive server**.

Phase it out: tell the customers that this server is going away as of X date.  After that time, they need to install a patch (assuming you have one) to stop it from using your DNS server.  This is done all the time.  Sysadmins, network admins, helpdesk guys, programmers?  We *get* it; this end-of-life thing happens all the time, because its standard operating procedure for a vendor/service provider/partner to tell us to stop using something after X date. We don't always like it, but its a fact of life in IT.

You say you don't have this issue on the current devices, so I'm assuming you've resolved this issue with a firmware update or patch. I know you said *you* can't touch the device, but surely they can?  I mean, if they're allowing these boxes to essentially phone home to you, they can't really be *that* anal about who's doing what to their devices; you could have a reverse proxy setup for all they know, so why not have them install a patch that fixes this or **tell them to use their own DNS servers**.  Surely your device supports DHCP; I can't think of a network device (not matter how old/frail/odd) that *doesn't*.

If you can't do that, the next thing to do is control **who can access your recursive server**: you say that it's "hard to tell" who's using it and how, but it's time to find out for certain and start dropping traffic that's not legitimate.

These are "quasi-military/government" organizations, right?  Well, they likely are part of a legitimate netblock that they own; these devices aren't home routers behind dynamic IPs.  Find out.  Contact them, explain the problem and how you are **saving them a lot of money by not forcing a firmware or product replacement** if only they can confirm the netblock/IP address that the device will be using to access your DNS server.

This is done all the time: I have several customers who restrict extranet access or HL7 listeners to healthcare partners in this way; it's **not that hard** to get them to fill out a form and provide the IP and/or netblock I should be expecting traffic from: if they want access to the extranet, they have to give me an IP or subnet.  And this is rarely a moving target so it's not like you're going to get inundated with hundreds of IP change requests every day: big campus hospital networks that own their own netblocks with hundreds of subnets and thousands and thousands of host IPs routinely give me a handful of IP addresses or a subnet I should be expecting; again, these aren't laptop users wandering all around campus all the time, so why would I expect to see UDP source packets from an ever-changing IP address?  Clearly I'm making I'm an assumption here, but I'll bet it's not as much as you think for < 100s of devices.  Yes, it'll be a lengthy ACL, and yes, it requires some maintenance and communication (gasp!) but its the next best thing outside of shutting it down completely.

If for some reason the channels of communication are not open (or somebody's too afraid or can't be bothered to contact these legacy device owners and do this properly), you need to to establish a baseline of normal usage/activity so you can formulate some other strategy that will *help* (but not prevent) your participation in DNS amplification attacks.

A long-running `tcpdump` should work filtering on incoming UDP 53 and verbose logging on the DNS server application.  I would also want to start collecting source IP addresses/netblocks/geoIP information (are all your clients in the US?  Block everything else) because, as you say, you're not *adding* any new devices, you're merely providing a legacy service to existing installations.

This will also help you understand **what record types are being requested, and for what domains, by whom, and how often**: for DNS amplification to work as intended, the attacker needs to be able to request a **large record type** (1) to a functioning **domain** (2).

1. "large record type": do your devices even need TXT or SOA records to be able to be resolved by your recursive DNS server? You may be able to specify which record types are valid on your DNS server; I believe it's possible with BIND and perhaps Windows DNS, but you'd have to do some digging.  If your DNS server responds with `SERVFAIL` to any TXT or SOA records, and least *that* response is an order of magnitude (or two) smaller than the payload that was intended.  Obviously you're still "part of the problem" because the spoofed victim would still be getting those `SERVFAIL` responses from your server, but at least you're not hammering them and perhaps your DNS server gets "delisted" from the harvested list(s) the bots use over time for not "cooperating".
2. "functioning domain": you may be able to whitelist only domains that are valid.  I do this on my hardened data center setups where the server(s) only need Windows Update, Symantec, etc. to function.  However, you're just mitigating the damage you're causing at this point: the victim would still get bombarded with `NXDOMAIN` or `SERVFAIL` responses from your server because your server would still respond to the forged source IP.  Again, Bot script might also automatically update it's open server list based on results, so this could get your server removed.

I'd also use some form of rate limiting, as others have suggested, either at the application level (i.e. message size, requests per client limitations) or the firewall level (see the other answers), but again, you're going to have to do some analysis to ensure you're not killing legitimate traffic.

An Intrusion Detection System that's been tuned and/or trained (again, need a baseline here) should be able to detect abnormal traffic over time by source or volume as well, but would likely take regular babysitting/tuning/monitoring to prevent false positives and/or see if it's actually preventing attacks.

At the end of the day, you have to wonder if all this effort is worth it or if you should just insist that the right thing is done and that's eliminating the problem in the first place.

Comment: Well, a patch is not possible. We don't even have working build hardware anymore for some platforms. As for the netblock they are expecting traffic from, they generally don't know. I'm not sure you appreciate how unusual the environment is that some of these devices are in. Some are on private networks where they have their own DNS scheme, and there may not even be anybody around anymore who even knows how the system was set up. We basically just have to keep it working until the contract ends.

Comment: Then the best you can do is bandaid the problem with rate limiting unless you're willing to do some analysis.  Honestly, if these systems are that static/neglected, chances are their footprint won't change and you could probably get away with layer 3 ACLs by source IP once you collect them all.

Comment: I'm thinking a hybrid approach. Whitelist IPs we can identify (maybe subject them to a high limit). Subject other IPs to a pretty low limit. Periodically audit to see if any IPs need to be whitelisted or removed from the whitelist.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz you might not even need a high limit.  Again, having a baseline of legit traffic would help immensely.

Answer (score 6):

It depends on the kind of rate limiting you want to do.

Rate limiting with `iptables` is really more intended for limiting incoming packets, since packets up to the limit will match the filter and have the specified target applied (e.g., `ACCEPT`). You would presumably have a subsequent target to `DROP` packets not matched by the filter. And although `iptables` has a `QUEUE` target it merely passes the packet to user space where you need to supply your own queuing application. You can also rate limit outgoing packets, but few people really want to start dropping outgoing traffic.

`iptables` rate limit dropping:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --port 53 -m hashlimit --hashlimit 1/minute --hashlimit-burst 5 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --port 53 -j DROP
```

Using `hashlimit` rather than `limit` will give you rate limiting per destination IP. I.e., five packets to 8.8.8.8 that hit the limit will prevent packets being sent to 8.8.4.4 while with `hashlimit` if 8.8.8.8 is maxed you can still reach 8.8.4.4, which sounds more like what you want.

If you don't want packets past the limit to be dropped then what you really want is `tc`. `tc` will regulate on the flow to get a nice steady stream rather than lots of bursty traffic. On the incoming side packets are delivered to the application slower but will all arrive in order. On the outgoing packets will leave your application as fast as possible but placed on the wire in a consistent stream.

I haven't used `tc` much, but here's an example of [rate limiting ICMP](http://lartc.org/lartc.html#LARTC.COOKBOOK.ICMP-RATELIMIT) which you can probably adapt easily for DNS.

Comment: My article in French about this setup (used for an actual open resolver): http://www.bortzmeyer.org/rate-limiting-dns-open-resolver.html

Answer (score 4):

Here's one thing you can do to potentially mitigate responses to spoofed queries, but it takes some work:

First, take a look at your log of the security channel and find an IP address that is getting spoofed.

Then run a tcpdump using that source IP (10.11.12.13) like this:

`tcpdump -n src 10.11.12.13 and udp dst port 53 -v -X -S`

You'll get something like this:

```
18:37:25.969485 IP (tos 0x0, ttl  52, id 46403, offset 0, flags [none], proto: UDP (17), length: 45) 10.11.12.13.51169 > 01.02.03.04.domain:  4215+ ANY? . (17)
        0x0000:  4500 002d b543 0000 3411 b9d9 0A0B 0C0D  E..-.C..4.......
        0x0010:  0102 0304 c7e1 0035 0019 0e89 1077 0100  .......5.....w..
        0x0020:  0001 0000 0000 0000 0000 ff00 0100       ..............
```

Now the fun part! Open up rfc1035 at https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc1035 and turn to section 4.1.1.

It's time to translate the results of the tcpdump and figure out a pattern we can use to create a packet level filter.

The ID of the header starts at 0x1C, so we've got some flags at 0x1E, the QDCOUNT at 0x20, the ANCOUNT at 0x22, the NSCOUNT at 0x24 and the ARCOUNT at 0x26.

That leaves the actual question at 0x28, which in this case is null (ROOT) for the NAME, 0xFF for QTYPE = ANY, and 0x01 for QCLASS = IN.

To make a longish story short, I've found that adding the following iptables rule blocks over 95% of the spoofed queries which are requesting ANY records IN ROOT:

`iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport domain -m u32 --u32 "0x28=0x0000ff00" -j DROP`

Your mileage may vary... hope this helps.

Answer (score 3):

Using `tc` and queueing disciplines in linux for outbound port 53 UDP:

```
IFACE=eth0    
tc qdisc  add dev ${IFACE} root handle 1: htb default 0
tc class  add dev ${IFACE} parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate   10mbit burst 20m
tc qdisc  add dev ${IFACE} parent 1:1 handle 10: sfq perturb 1
tc filter add dev ${IFACE} protocol ip parent 1:0 prio 1 handle 1 fw flowid 1:1
```

Will set you up with a `disc` limited to 10mbit for any packet with firewall mark '1'.
Firewall markings are only internal to the firewall, and don't modify the packet.  Just the handling of the packet by the queueing discipline.
Here is how you use `iptables` to make the firewall markings:

```
iptables -A PREROUTING -o eth0 -p udp --sport 53 -t mangle -j MARK --set-mark 1
iptables -A PREROUTING -o eth0 -p udp --dport 53 -t mangle -j MARK --set-mark 1
```

Modify to your liking to exclude trusted subnets and/or destinations.  The `-o eth0` limits the shaping to outbound packets only.  Hope this helps.

Comment: DNS uses UDP and TCP...

Answer (score 1):

depending on the network 'position' you're in [having multiple bgp feeds or being at the 'end' of the internet - as a stub network] you can try something like [uRPF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/URPF#Unicast_RPF_.28uRPF.29) to prevent source address spoofing.

[other](http://www.cisco.com/en/US/docs/ios/12_2t/12_2t13/feature/guide/ft_urpf.html) source of info.

Comment: You can only use uRPF to stop your own clients from spoofing. So the only way uRPF would do me any good was if I got everyone else to use it. I'm not worried about attacks launched by my own customers. I'm worried about attacks coming in from the Internet. There's no way to run uRPF on a non-client connection. Either asymmetric routing is the norm (if you have more than one real link), or every route points out that connection (if you have only one real link).

Comment: @DavidSchwartz i've decided to un-delete my response. i understand it's not very helpful in your case but might be useful for others. interesting case btw - i'm curious about other answers to come.

Answer (score 1):

I'd try to compose a list of all clients that rely on your externally facing recursive resolvers.  Start with a day or so of packet traces on the DNS boxes.  From there, begin creating iptables rules to allow that traffic you recognize and authorize.  The default will eventually be to drop traffic to 53/tcp and 53/udp.  If that breaks something, fine tune your rules.

Answer (score 1):

Are these devices still under a support contract?  If so, reach out to your customers.  Let them know that the internet has evolved a little in the last decade and in order to continue to provide name resolution for these devices you'll need to know the SRC IP to expect queries from.  Set a date ~6 months in the future at which time you will no longer be able to service unknown clients, and stick to it.  This is a pretty common in the industry.  If these devices are no longer under a support contract... sounds like a business decision. How long does your company intend to expend resources on ancient product that no longer generates revenue?

These sound like specialized devices, are they so specialized that you can reasonably predict which domains to expect legitimate queries for?  bind supports views, create a public view that only does recursion for those domains.

Use this as a learning opportunity, if you have not already done so, stop releasing products where you do not have the ability to fix bugs.  That's what this is, a bug.  One that will certainly EOL this device prematurely, sooner or later.

Comment: Reading some other answers. You say you can't really even develop a patch because you no longer have the hardware to test it on. This being the case, how valid are any of your current support contracts anyway?  What would you do if one of these 'supported' devices experiences a hardware failure?  Do the same thing here.

Comment: We don't support the hardware. We're not even allowed to *touch* the hardware. If the hardware fails, it's destroyed and replaced. We're supporting the remote infrastructure, and have to do so by contract until 2015. (It's not that we don't have the hardware to test on, it's that we can't do the testing. Any changes require an approval that is no longer possible to get because the approval standard has expired. Welcome to dealing with governments.)

Answer (score 1):

From nanog somewhere, this:

```
iptables -A INPUT -p udp --dport 53 -m hashlimit \
--hashlimit-name DNS --hashlimit-above 20/second --hashlimit-mode srcip \
--hashlimit-burst 100 --hashlimit-srcmask 28 -j DROP
```

This is not ideal.  It might be better to allow fewer packets per second, and have a higher burst.

Answer (score -1):

Here is a solution that I've used a couple of times against DDOS attacks, it's not perfect but  helped me out. The solution consists in a script that is being called each N minutes(like 1,2,3 etc. minutes) by the cron and blocks IP's that are creating a number of connections bigger then the given one in the script:

```
#!/bin/sh

PORT_TO_CHECK="53"
CONNECTION_LIMIT="20"
IPTABLES="/sbin/iptables"

netstat -an > /tmp/netstat.tmp
Buf_var1=`cat /tmp/netstat.tmp | grep -v "LISTEN"| grep ":$PORT_TO_CHECK\ " | grep -v "0.0.0.0" | awk '{print $5}' | grep -v ":$PORT_TO_CHECK$" | sed -e 's/^::ffff://g' -e 's/:.*$//g' | sort | uniq`
i=0
banned_flag=0
for conn in `for i in $Buf_var1; do echo -n "$i "; cat /tmp/netstat.tmp | grep -c $i;done | grep -v "=\ 0"`;do
[ $i = 0 ] && connip=$conn && i=1
[ $i = 2 ] && {
connum=$conn
[ $connum -ge $CONNECTION_LIMIT ] && {
[ "$var_test" = "" ] && {
$IPTABLES -I INPUT -s $connip -j DROP
banned_flag=1
}
}
}
[ $banned_flag = 1 ] && i=0
[ $i = 1 ] && i=2
done
rm -f /tmp/netstat.tmp
```

Comment: I don't think it will work: DNS is request/reply over UDP and do not leave open connections.